# Giving a method to an object prototype that points at the value of that objects own properties

Tags: javascript

I writing a small program that takes the English and the Spanish version of a word from two user inputs and stores them as objects:

```
function Dictionary(english, foreign){
    this.english = english;
    this.foreign = foreign; 
}
```

Thes objects are then stored in an array; objectsArray[].
I then assign a method to the "Dictionary" prototype to make the inputted strings into uppercase:

```
Dictionary.prototype.capMethod = function(){
    this.english.toUpperCase();
    this.foreign.toUpperCase();
}
```

Once the user has then inputted all the translations (which they will later be tested on), I try to call the dictionaries' capMethod:

```
for(var x in objectsArray){
                objectsArray[x].capMethod();
                console.log(objectsArray[x].english + objectsArray[x].foreign + typeof objectsArray[x].english); }
```

The console, however, does not suggest they have been changed to uppercase. This is corroborated when the english and foreign values are returned to the user (later in the program) still as they were inputted.

I stress that there are other parts of the program where I could make this change but not understanding my mistake here seems like a poor reason to do it another way.

I do need to capitalise the strings that are stored in the dictionaries and there is ALOT of code around it so a JSfiddle would be cumbersome, I hope the above will be enough as the problem really seems to lie in the way I'm referencing the objects values. I also know there are several subtly different ways to reference object properties but I'm new to javascript and am struggling to wrap my head around it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `toUpperCase()` doesn't change a string (because strings are immutable). It returns a new string. You will need to explicitly assign that to your property if you want to mutate your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function

```
Dictionary.prototype.capMethod = function(){
    this.english.toUpperCase();
    this.foreign.toUpperCase();
}
```

the result of the 'toUpperCase()' is not used.

```
this.english = this.english.toUpperCase();
```

would be better.

Would storing objects like this work for you?:

```
function store(english,foreign){
  objectsArray.push({
    english:english.toUpperCase(),
    foreign:foreign.toUpperCase())
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much - this is exactly the kind of input that I needed.